# 日本語に違和感: あなたは自分自身の回答を承認できます: H時間後

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

[image: あなたは自分自身の回答を承認できます]

- できるのかできないのか、わかりにくい

Answer (score 1):

> 質問してから48時間は自分の回答をベストアンサーに選ぶことができません。$acceptTime$まで待ってください。

Comment: 翻訳ストリングの中では「○○時間後」を変えると複数の箇所にも適用してしまうため、「：」の前のストリングでなんとか調整可能ですか？「あなたは自分自身の回答を承認できます: $acceptTime$」

Comment: @jmac 「○○時間後」を想定した言いかたにしてみました